# JQuery: Iterate array of objects and append the value of object attribute to <ul>

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects that are returned from a `fetch()` response. I  sort them alphabetically and store the sorted array in `sortedComments`.

The comments have multiple keys, such as `linkId`, `time_created`, however I'm just trying to get the `body` out of each comment and append these to a `comments_section` div that I have in my view.

Below is my code:

```
function sortComments() {
$("#sort_comments").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var buttonData = document.getElementById("sort_comments").dataset.linkid

    fetch(`/links/${buttonData}/comments.json`)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(comments => {
        const sortedComments = comments.sort(({body: a}, {body: b}) => a.localeCompare(b))
        console.log(sortedComments) 
        var $ul = $("div.comments_section ul")
        $ul.append(sortedComments.body)
        })
      })
    }
```

The `console.log(sortedComments)` shows the array of comments alphabetized, but I don't know which function I need to iterate in the array and get the `body` of each `comment`.

I've seen resources online that suggest `for..in` and `object.getOwnProperty` but I haven't seen it used on arrays like the one I have.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the `comments` array?

Comment: Check `sortedComments.forEach((idx, comment) => console.log(comment.body))` as one starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can achieve this via a `for .. of` loop as shown:

```
fetch(`/links/${buttonData}/comments.json`)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(comments => {
    const sortedComments = comments.sort(({body: a}, {body: b}) => a.localeCompare(b))

    var $ul = $("div.comments_section ul")

    /*
    Use For .. of loop to iterate comment value objects of 
    sortedComments array
    */
    for(const comment of sortedComments) {
        /*
        Create li element for this comment body text for use in the
        list
        */            
        var $li = $('<li>');
        $li.text(comment.body);

        /*
        Append li element for this comment body text to the $ul
        */
        $ul.append($li)
    }

    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dacre_Denny! It worked. The only thing I need to do is clear the existing comments list. I appreciate the help

Comment: @James you're welcome! If you want to clear the existing list before you `append()` to it, you can call  `$ul.empty()` before the `for` loop :-)

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, and since [JQuery::append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) supports an array as the argument, I will use [Array::map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `sortedComments` and then use this as the argument of the `append()`.

```
fetch(`/links/${buttonData}/comments.json`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(comments =>
    {
        const sortedComments = comments.sort(
            ({body: a}, {body: b}) => a.localeCompare(b)
        );
        var $ul = $("div.comments_section ul");
        $ul.append(sortedComments.map(comment => comment.body));
    });
});
```

Note that you can also map every comment to some `html` markup that fit your needs, example:

```
sortedComments.map(comment => "<li>" + comment.body + "</li>");
```